# Is iText 5.4.2 open source?

Tags: java, itext

I would like to know whether iText 5.4.2 is a open source. I know it is described here well:

http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/index.php

But I am confused as the page also says this:

> Buying such a license is mandatory as soon as you develop commercial
>   activities distributing the iText software inside your product or
>   deploying it on a network without disclosing the source code of your
>   own applications under the AGPL license. These activities include:
>   offering paid services to customers as an ASP, serving PDFs on the fly
>   in the cloud or in a web application, shipping iText with a closed
>   source product.

Comment: You seem to think *open source* implies *open for any kind of use by anyone.* That is wrong, *open source* only means that the source is open and can be accessed. It does not mean that it can be used freely. The *terms of use* you found tell you how you are actually allowed to use the source.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AGPL stands for [Affero GPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License).

It *basically* says, when you want to sell a software product that includes iText or use iText in any commercial webservice, than you need to buy a license.

If you do an open source (with an approriate license) or private project, than you are fine and don't need to buy a license.

Comment: *If you do an open source (with an approriate license)* - AGPL actually is fairly strict. Thus, essentially the only *appropriate license* is AGPL again.

Comment: Like I understand Afero, even if you make a SaaS you still need to provide a link to source code somewhere... I mean, it seem a lot "get the code" than probably GPL >= 2... or Im wrong?

Answer (score 7):

iText 5.4.2 is open source, because the source is openly available for everybody - so the answer to your question is **yes**. However your question and your definition of open source might be a different one:

Depending on the license you are able to use an open source project in a commercial project without the need to also opensource the whole source code of that project under that license.

If that was the question then **no**: AGPL licensed projects can not be used in commercial projects (without open sourcing the commercial project which is a nogo for most commercial projects)

The last iText version released under a less restrictive license (commercially usable) was iText 2.1.7 (java) and 4.1.6 (c#). It was both released under MPL / LGPL.  Even though the authors removed it from the sourceforge page you are able to find it in many places in the web (e.g. maven central). Those versions are from 2009 and still do their job fine, if you need the latest pdf features however (newer versions of digital signatures, ...) or experience a bug you may have to use the latest version...

**Update**: There was an unofficial java version 4.2.0 but you have to build it for yourself.

**Update II**: There is a fork called '[OpenPDF](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF)' which continues based on that version. Today I would use that project.

Comment: Thanks for info. You saved my search job. :) I needed version 2.1.7.

Comment: https://github.com/ymasory/iText-4.2.0 is java... and it is version 4.2.0 `iText is a Java PDF library originally dual licensed under MPL/LGPL` not 2.1.7. And you can make it compatible with 5.0 see at end of fork.

Comment: @Lonzak in mvnrepository.com i see latest version is 4.2.2 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/4.2.2, is that one MPL/LGPL licenced as well?

Comment: @AleksandarT No. If you look at the license it is AGPL.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, yes, iText is open source. The long answer is the next paragraph.

The Affero GPL provides some restrictions, which they would be happy to remove, if you buy a license. For example, you must disclose your source code for apps based on iText, but if you do not want to do that, you can buy a commercial license, freeing you from the AGPL.