# Java convert dynamic generated HTML content to PDF

Tags: java, javascript

Recently I am working on commercial project which requires to generate a PDF based on some dynamic HTML content, now I have implemented that with a java library called *WKHTMLTOPDF (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)*.

This library is a command line tool which user browser webkit as rendering engine, since I am new to java development, **I am not sure whether there is any security or performance issue when using this library**.

If this is not a good solution, **is javascript plugin an alternative**?

Sorry for my english!:)

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on the same sort of thing recently. I used iText and found it immensely useful. I haven't used WKHTMLTOPDF but I'm answering since you seem to explore more on other options which could be better, safer. iText has been here for a long while now, and it's pretty simple to use.

Follow these links for more info on iText,
[How to convert HTML to PDF using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825782/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itext)

And,
[Converting HTML files to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf)

A small/sleek tutorial http://hmkcode.com/itext-html-to-pdf-using-java/

If you are concerned about any sort of licensing issues follow,

[Is iText 5.4.2 open source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940631/is-itext-5-4-2-open-source)

I found iText quite handy and is supported by a most of the browsers too. (Chrome, IE, Firefox, I haven't tested on res of them) Hope this helps.

Comment: the commercial license of iText is too expensive, since we have server cluster which have more than 14 server instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use PD4ML library available purely in JAVA .It is easy to use and generates PDF from HTML (dom) quickly.

http://www.pd4ml.com/